# How to display the panel on the right side of the row once clicked on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have compiled a table using CSS and HTML. After clicking on a given row of the table, I would like a small panel to appear next to the current row.

Graphic example:
[image: Graphic example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I have managed to make the clicked line colored with a given color

Comment: Important that you put your code so far into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.